# Unable to open or even add Resource files in my Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Every single time i either try to open or add a resource file to my project or just open it within delphi it will throw me an error (I have tried .rc,.res,.rc..all kinds of extensions) and it will say that the file has been truncated or that Delphi cannot open or add this type of file. any ideas?

Comment: The resource file has been compiled with brcc?

Comment: What are the EXACT steps you are performing?  What are the EXACT errors?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open a `.res` file in the Code Editor, as it is a binary file.  You can open an `.rc` file, as it is a plain text file.

You can certainly add both `.rc` and `.res` files to a project, though.  The IDE should not complain about that.